# Vector type or namespace unknown

Tags: c#

Simple, code below doesn't recognize `Vector`, and I've got `using System.Numerics.Vectors` already.

```
private Double crossProductExample()
{
    Vector vector1 = new Vector(20, 30);
    Vector vector2 = new Vector(45, 70);
    Double crossProduct;

    // crossProduct is equal to 50    
    crossProduct = Vector.CrossProduct(vector1, vector2);

    return crossProduct;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to implement steering behaviors through vectors. I managed to implement seek without vectors, but it seems it would be all better with vectors, but I can't make them work inside C#.

Comment: My answer solved your issue? If yes please mark as answered :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a Reference to **System.Windows** AND **WindowsBase**

[image: Reference]

[image]

Comment: I did as you said, but same problem. Did you do it in WPF or windows forms though?

Comment: Windows forms and Console App, you are using ?? Windows Form?

Comment: I am using windows forms app as I said in title,but it was edited by someone.

Comment: Right click in Project, Add Reference, (Assemblies/Framework) and Select WindowsBase. Then go to your project and Add using System.Windows;  was exactly what i Did.

Comment: I updated my answer with a full image of my solution.

Comment: It works now, I had to right click on project. not go on top menu project->add reference

Comment: yes :) you need to. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want `System.Windows.Vector`. So add `using System.Windows` to your using statements. You'll also need a reference to the `WindowsBase` assembly in your project.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but when I use using System.Windows, I don't fix it. 
If I write using System.Windows.Vectors; I get note that there is no Vectors in System.Windows.

Comment: need WindowsBase as well :)  then this works.

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro Right. System.Windows.Vector is in the WindowsBase.dll assembly. Without that being referenced by the project it the Using can't find anything. I'm just used to VS/Intellisense auto-adding references now so I don't think about it. I'll update the answer, thanks.